Intuition of weak and weak* Topology on dual space
If we take any normed space $X$ and observe their dual space $X^*$ we can compare different topologies on the space: That is the norm topology on $X^*$ ($\tau^*$), weak topology ($\tau_w$) and weak$*$ topology ($\tau_{w*}$). I am trying to find an intuition to "show" that $$\tau_w \subseteq \tau^*.$$ I know that the weak topology on the dual is the coarsest topology such that any function $x^*: X^* \to \mathbb{K}$ is continous (where $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$). So intuitively I need to leave out on some open sets of $\tau^*$ in order for all functions $x^*$ to be continous. Is this right?
And if I want to compare $\tau_{w^*} \supseteq \tau_w$ I can then argue that (since the weak$*$ topology only considers any functions in the embedding $\iota(X) \subseteq X^{**}$) that by considering less functions I can admit more open sets?

You delete some  open sets form $\tau^$ to form  $\tau_w$, but that's not to make the functionals in $X^$ continuous. They were already continuous with $\tau^$ (and besides, if some functions weren't continuous, you'd have to add more open sets in the domain to make them continuous). The reason for deletion is to get the weakest (i.e., smallest)  topology that still makes every element of $X^$ continuous. Similar comments apply to $\tau_{w*}$ and show that it's weaker than $\tau_w$.
